# Invite your Facebook friends in web app - Styled like Facebook or native web app style?

Tags: gui-design, facebook

I am not sure how to decide (other than testing and doing the work twice), whether users when prompted to invite their Facebook friends, would be more comfortable with 'wall of faces' that is styled like the native app, or like Facebook.

By style, I mean fonts, colours text sizes and layout.

A mockup I'm working on, which loosely resembles the native style (see image below).

I would love some guidance on how to proceed.

## **Native style:**

[image: native style]

---

## **Facebook style:**

[image: facebook style]

Comment: Well, UX is all about testing. It's either you're testing on your own or you're using someone else's test results.

Comment: @dnbrv — Do you know where the best place is to look for "someone else's test results" for something like this?

Comment: @DesignerGuy: 1) [Google](http://www.google.com/); 2) [WhichTestWon](https://whichtestwon.com/past-tests); 3) UX StackExchange; 4) [UX Pond](http://www.uxpond.com/) (custom Google search for UX resources)

Answer (score 4):

Based on personal experience, **I'm more comfortable with the "Facebook style"**.

There is something that almost seems invasive about the native style. As a user, I find myself asking, where did they get this information? The "Facebook style" makes it clear that it is feeding in from my Facebook account. This could be solved with a clear headline with the Facebook logo that says "Invite Friends from Facebook".

I feel like Pinterest does this decently.

[image: Pinterest Facebook Invite Screenshot]

Comment: @BennySkogberg - Thanks! Do you know if there are any good resources that cover the concept of information origin?

Comment: Not really, sorry. But I think its good design to make applications as transparent as possible. If you use someone else’s service (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Foursquare etc. …), make it look like the service your using even if you can do your own design.

Comment: @BennySkogberg - Fair enough. I agree, transparency helps users feel more comfortable (even if they don't consciously realize it).

Answer (score 0):

This is your app, it has distinct branding & UI. I believe you should go with "native" style, however you do need to message where you got list of friends from.